# How do I align sizes when using flex and line-height+vh?

Tags: html, css

I got [pretty close to what I want](https://jsfiddle.net/wpnqyh5d/) however I think the 32vh is what's ruining my size.

When I use `img {height: 100%;}` they become too big so I settled down for 32vh; However the left and right div are a few pixels off. It's especially noticeable if you zoom in a little (press ctrl+'+'). It happens on both firefox and chrome. I tried using 50% and 100% height on the images and putting position relative on testB but it didn't seem to help. How do I make both size equal height? I don't mind if there's extra pixels between the right two divs but they must be same height as left aka div a

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

.test {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.testA {
  background-color: black;
  width: 61.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 18px;
  line-height: 65vh;
}

.testB {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 32vh;
  position: relative;
}

.testC {
  background-color: royalblue;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.testD {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: purple;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.test img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.testA img {
  height: 100%;
}

.testC img {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 32vh;
}

.testD img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 32vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      c
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      d
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reduce this a code a bit, because for just showing off the problem, you don't need three "test" divs, just one will do. And then you can turn it into a short, runnable snippet.

Comment: do u want to have both testA and testB  of same height?

Comment: @AmareshSM Yes.

Comment: check out my answer @UnixUser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

```html
<style>
  body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .test {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 65vh;
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .testA {
    background-color: black;
    width: 61.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 18px;
    line-height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .testB {
    background-color: green;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: 32vh;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .testC {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: royalblue;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .testD {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: purple;
    flex-grow: 1;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  
  .testA img {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .testC img {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 32.5vh;
  }
  
  .testD img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 32.5vh;
  }
</style>

<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      c
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      d
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="test">
  <div class="testA">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
  </div>
  <div class="testB">
    <div class="testC">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
    </div>
    <div class="testD">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I copied pasted it to my test file wrong but it seems like it's stretching the width of the image instead of centering it. But the height is indeed fixed. I'm going through the code right now

Answer (score 1):

not quit sure if I understand your question, but here is my approach.
Use "background-image" instead and then background-size: cover;

```
<style>
    body * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color:white;
    }

    .test {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        height: 65vh;
        width: 80vw;
        display: flex;
    }
    .testA {
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/500x300);
    width: 61.5%;
  }

    .testB {
        background-color: green;
        flex-grow:1;
        line-height: 32vh;
        text-align: right;
        position: relative;
    }

    .testC {
            background-image: url(https://placehold.it/500x300);
margin-bottom: 6  px;
background-size: cover;
    }

    .testD {
            background-image: url(https://placehold.it/500x300);
margin-bottom: 10px;
background-size: cover;
    }

    .test img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .testA img {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .testC img {
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 32vh;
    }

    .testD img {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 32vh;
    }

</style>

<div class="test">
    <div class="testA">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="testB">
        <div class="testC">
            c
        </div>
        <div class="testD">
            d
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```